# СПП изьяснительное?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Он уже не верил тому, что было с ним когда-то такое: дом отдыха, озеро, синяя лодка и женщина, щупающая ладошкой воду за бортом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это сложноподчиненное предложение, в состав которого входит придаточное изъяснительное. Связующий элемент — союз *что* и указательное слово *тому*. По-моему, вы уже задавали схожий вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ исчерпывающий, примите его (надо нажать на кнопку справа от ответа).